# Exportar tabla HTML a excel con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, exportar

Tengo una proyecto con `laravel` en `ubuntu` (no puedo hacerlo con `laravel-excel` porque no cuento con los accesos para instalar los paquetes) en donde hago reportes y los muestro en una tabla y quiero exportarlas con `javascript`.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no ocurre la descarga, ya intente varios métodos, vi muchos videos sobre el tema y sigue sin funcionar.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo o que método me pueden recomendar?

script:

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@latest/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/file-saverjs@latest/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport@latest/dist/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Tabla: El formato del archivo es .blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <button type="button" id="btnExportar" class=" btn btn-success">Exportar <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span></button>
</div>
<br>
<table id="PuntosCanjeados" class="table table-striped table-responsive col-lg-10 text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Puntos asignados</th>
            <th scope="col">$</th>
            <th scope="col">Puntos redimidos</th>
            <th scope="col">$</th>
            <th scope="col">Porcentaje</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($result['points'] as $points)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $points->nombre }}</th>
            <th>{{ $points->puntos }}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($points->puntos / $points->tipo_cambio) }}</th>
            <th>{{ $points->puntos_usados }}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($points->puntos_usados / $points->tipo_cambio) }}</th>
            <th>{{ $points->porcentaje }} %</th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="text-success">Total</th>
            <th>{{ $result['points_total']->p1 }}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($result['points_total']->p1 / $points->tipo_cambio) }}</th>
            <th>{{ $result['points_total']->p2 }}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($result['points_total']->p2 / $points->tipo_cambio) }}</th>
            <th>{{ round(($result['points_total']->p2 / $result['points_total']->p1)*100,2) }} %</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
<script >
    //btnExportar
    //PuntosCanjeados
    const $btnExportar = document.querySelector("#btnExportar"),
    $tabla = document.querySelector("#PuntosCanjeados");

    $btnExportar.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let tableExport = new TableExport($tabla, {
        exportButtons: false,
        filename: "Puntos Canjeados",
        sheetname: "Puntos Canjeados",
        });
        let datos = tableExport.getExportData();
        let preferenciasDocumento = datos.tabla.xlsx;
        tableExport.export2file(preferenciasDocumento.data, preferenciasDocumento.mimeType, preferenciasDocumento.filename, preferenciasDocumento.fileExtension, preferenciasDocumento.merges, preferenciasDocumento.RTL, preferenciasDocumento.sheetname);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para fines prácticos al `html` le puse datos de prueba y eliminé los estilos, pero lo puedes adaptar a tu código.

El código está escrito en `javascript` puro sin dependencias de librerías y está basado en [este artículo](https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/).

En el `snippet` de este sitio no descarga el archivo, pero lo probé en `jsfiddle` y si lo descarga.

```js
function htmlExcel(idTabla, nombreArchivo = '') {
  let linkDescarga;
  let tipoDatos = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  let tablaDatos = document.getElementById(idTabla);
  let tablaHTML = tablaDatos.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

  // Nombre del archivo
  nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo ? nombreArchivo + '.xlsx' : 'Reporte_Puntos_Canjeados.xlsx';

  // Crear el link de descarga
  linkDescarga = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(linkDescarga);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tablaHTML], {
      type: tipoDatos
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, nombreArchivo);
  } else {
    // Crear el link al archivo
    linkDescarga.href = 'data:' + tipoDatos + ', ' + tablaHTML;

    // Setear el nombre de archivo
    linkDescarga.download = nombreArchivo;

    //Ejecutar la función
    linkDescarga.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="htmlExcel('PuntosCanjeados', 'Reporte_Puntos_Canjeados')">Exportar reporte</button>

<table id="PuntosCanjeados">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Puntos asignados</th>
      <th>$</th>
      <th>Puntos redimidos</th>
      <th>$</th>
      <th>Porcentaje</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan Valdéz</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>50000</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>1000000</td>
      <td>10%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pablo Neruda</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>500000</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Edgar Alán Poe</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>2000000</td>
      <td>50%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Y el resultado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese articulo ya lo intente y no me funciono, el proyecto lo tengo en un servidor de linux, ¿No tendrá algo que ver?, porque ya intente varios métodos y no me ejecuta la descarga

Answer (score -2):

Si lo que quieres es Exportar o Descargar los datos de una tabla ya desplegados en el DOM puedes hacerlo con la siguiente librería en GitHub: https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        td, th {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }
        
        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a id="download_xls" download="filename.xls" href="#">Export to Excel</a>
    <a id="download_csv" download="filename.csv" href="#">Export to CSV</a>
    <a id="download_xlsx" href="#">Export to CSV</a>

    <table id="datatable">
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
      </table>    

    <!-- js section -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/excellentexport@3.4.3/dist/excellentexport.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
        let download_xls = document.querySelector("#download_xls")
        download_xls.addEventListener("click", ()=>{                     
            ExcellentExport.excel(download_xls, 'datatable')
        })

        let download_csv = document.querySelector("#download_csv")
        download_csv.addEventListener("click", ()=>{                     
            ExcellentExport.csv(download_csv, 'datatable');
        })

        let download_xlsx = document.querySelector("#download_xlsx")
        download_xlsx.addEventListener("click", ()=>{                     
            ExcellentExport.convert({ anchor: download_xlsx, filename: 'filename', format: 'xlsx'},[{name: 'Sheet Name Here 1', from: {table: 'datatable'}}])
        })

    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En ésta comunidad no podemos limitarnos a responder con código sin más, deberías de explicar lo que hace y como lo hace para despejar las dudas de la persona que pregunta. Al final le puedes estar dando la solución a sus demandas, pero seguirá con la duda de porque no sabía hacerlo o cual era su error.

Comment: Esta comunidad esta hecha para dar soluciones a problemas que surgen a diario como programadores que somos, Una explicación en este tipo de pregunta no es necesaria, si quiere más detalle de lo que hace y no hace un Código que busque uno de los miles de tutoriales que hay en internet

Comment: Pues no @aldwip34, aquí no todos somos programadores, yo simplemente soy un aprendiz, y preferiría respuestas detalladas con explicación concienzuda del código y de las correcciones de los errores. También es cierto que muchos "programadores", se limitan a buscar el código de sus respuestas por internet, lo copian, lo pegan y lo publican sin saber ellos mismos lo que hace ni como lo hace. Su afán es conseguir reputación. Pero seguro que no sea tu caso.

Comment: Creo que no entendiste como funciona esta comunidad. Por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]... las respuestas tienen que ser completas, con el codigo, la explicacion del problema, y como se soluciona.

Comment: @Joseba ¿qué cosa no entiendes? para explicarte

Comment: @gbianchi el código no necesita de una explicación ya que es bien sencillo, si quieres conocer más de lo que hace, ahí deje el enlace a github. Por cierto el código no lo copie y peque de internet, fue un ejemplo que realice para quién formuló la pregunta, si no esta satisfecho lo invito a publicar su respuesta con más detalles

Comment: Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). Por eso se pide que expliques el mismo. Tu enlace tampoco aporta nada, ya que es a una libreria de terceros que mañana puede desaparecer. Podes escribir las respuestas como quieras, pero no podes decir que porque es simple no hay que explicarlo.

Comment: Mira bien las etiquetas de la pregunta (javascript, html, excel, etc..) No es C# o C++. Todo el que tiene por lo menos un conocimiento básico de javascript sabe lo que son los eventos click, variables y manipulación de HTML. Tu crítica se basa en que usa una librería, todos los programadores usan librerías, dice un dicho que no hay que reinventar la rueda, además una librería no desaparece porque si. Otra vez le invito a publicar su respuesta en vez de estar criticando los aportes